# Extract a subset of the test set filtered by a condition

Tags: numpy, filter, scikit-learn, subset, test-data

I have split my data set into training and test:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=0)
```

then I computed a predictor and associated score. I now want to see how this predictor performs with a subset of the data that meets certain condition.

**I need to extract a subset of X_test and the corresponding y_**test.

For illustration purposes

```
X_test = [[9.3400e+01 9.4710e+01 1.2100e+03 0.0000e+00 0.0000e+00 0.0000e+00 1.0000e+00]
          [9.1210e+01 9.1890e+01 1.3600e+03 0.0000e+00 1.0000e+00 0.0000e+00 0.0000e+00]
          [8.8810e+01 9.0790e+01 1.3400e+03 0.0000e+00 0.0000e+00 0.0000e+00 1.0000e+00]]
y_test = [0 1 0]
```

and condition:

```
 (X_test[i][4]== 1)
```

I should end up with

```
X_test_cond = [[9.1210e+01 9.1890e+01 1.3600e+03 0.0000e+00 1.0000e+00 0.0000e+00 0.0000e+00]]
y_test_cond = [1]
```

How do I filter X_test and keep the corresponding indices to create the associated y_test subset?

Answer (score 1):

```
X_test_cond = X_test[y_test == 1]
```

returns in X_test_cond the instances of X_test corresponding to the indexes where y_test is equal to 1.

Answer (score 0):

So here is an answer... but it is purely procedural...

```
X_test_tmp = []
y_test_tmp = []
for i in range(len(X_test)):
    if X_test[i][4] == 1:
        X_test_tmp.append(X_test[i])
        y_test_tmp.append(y_test[i])
X_test_cond = np.array(X_test_tmp)
y_test_cond = np.array(y_test_tmp)
```

can we do it in less lines?